# How to get Html.DropdownFor() to select current element?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I must be missing something simple here. This code was working and i can't seem to figure out why it stopped.

First, I generate a selectlist in the controller like this:

```
        // Select List
        ViewData["FieldTypesList"] = new SelectList(
            genesisRepository.FieldTypes, "ftID", "ftName"
            );
```

The View that uses this select list looks like this:

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Genesis.Domain.Entities.Stream2FieldTypes>" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="Genesis.Domain.Entities" %>        
    <%: Html.DropDownListFor(
            model => model.FieldTypeID,
            (SelectList)ViewData["FieldTypesList"]
            )%>
    <%:Model.FieldTypeID.ToString() %>
```

However... the HTML that gets generated shows this:

```
<select id="Stream2FieldTypes_0_" name="Stream2FieldTypes[0]"><option value="1">Text Area</option>
    <option value="2">Text Box</option>
    <option value="3">Rich Text</option>
    <option value="4">Image</option>
    <option value="5">DateTime</option>
    <option value="6">Decimal</option>
    <option value="7">Integer</option>
</select>
3 <!--FYI: current value-->
```

I am completely missing why the view does not render html that selects 3 (Rich Text).

Do you guys see anything wrong with my thought process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @hunter and @John_Hartstock for pointing me to the selectlist instance rather than focusing on the DropDownListFor() method.

I ended up solving the bug by constructing the selectlist in the view instead of the controlelr. The controller was edited to this:

```
ViewData["FieldTypesList"] = genesisRepository.FieldTypes;
// Returns IEnumerable of FieldTypes
```

Changed the view to this:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(
            model => model.FieldTypeID, 
            new SelectList((IEnumerable<FieldTypes>)ViewData["FieldTypesList"],
            "ftID",
            "ftName",
            Model.FieldTypeID ))
%>
```

This works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to pass the selected value to the constructor

```
ViewData["FieldTypesList"] = new SelectList(
    genesisRepository.FieldTypes, "ftID", "ftName", myModel.FileTypeID)
);
```

Comment: When I construct the selectlist, I don't know what the selected value is yet. I send a viewmodel to the view and the same select list is used for multiple elements in the viewmodel.

Comment: Besides, I thought the line in my view: `model => model.FieldTypeID` was supposed to specify the select value.

Comment: try casting the FieldTypeID to int. `(int)model.FieldTypeID` I'm guessing that's an enum?

Comment: or try `model.FieldTypeID.ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it in your Controller with an overload of the [SelectList Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

```
    ViewData["FieldTypesList"] = new SelectList(
        genesisRepository.FieldTypes, "ftID", "ftName"
        new (ftID=3, ftName="Rich Text");
```

Comment: I don't think I can use this syntax. the view I showed above is actually part of an Editor Template, and it's displayed using EditorFor(). Ultimately, there could be a number of these "FieldType" select boxes on the page. It depends on which record is being called up. I can't hardcode the values of the select list in the controller because that selectlist is on the page multiple times.